# Django how to GET data from two tables and combine data in GET request in views

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

These are the django models that I currently have:

```py
class Desgn_Mast(models.Model):
    desgn_mast_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    desgn_name_short = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Desgn_Trans(models.Model):
    desgn_trans_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    emp_mast_id = models.ForeignKey("app.Emp_Mast",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desgn_mast = models.ForeignKey("app.Desgn_Mast",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField()

class Emp_Mast(models.Model):
    emp_mast_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The Desgn_Trans table mantains the history of all the designations an employee has ever had. Now in the view of Emp_Mast, in the GET request I want to also obtain the desgn of the employee

The example of the view is:

```py
class Emp_Mast_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Emp_Mast
        fields = "__all__"

class Emp_Mast_ListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [DjangoCustomModelPermissions]
    queryset = Task_Mast.objects.none() # TO define a dummy queryset for the purpose of the above permission class

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        db_data = Emp_Mast.objects.all()
        serializer = Emp_Mast_Serializer(db_data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want the following output for the GET request, how to do it?

```
{
 {
   emp_mast_id: 1,
   first_name: "Test",
   last_name: "User",
   desgn_mast: 1 (primary key of the respective desgn),
 },
 {...},
 {...}, 
}
```

Comment: Can you share the serilizer class that you're using.
Quick tip: Be explicit with the naming, this will make your code more readable, like Employee_Master or whatever

Comment: Here I added the serializer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved from a reverse lookup in the models class. A field for desgn can be defined in the Emp_Mast model using the @property decorator. This makes the model quick as reverse lookup is faster than querying an additional table and makes the structure easy to understand as you can think of desgn_mast as just another field of Emp_Mast

```
class Emp_Mast(models.Model):
    emp_mast_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def desgn(self):
        desgn_trans = self.desgn_trans_set.order_by('emp_mast_id','-priority').distinct('emp_mast_id')
        if desgn_trans.exists():
            entry = desgn_trans.first()
            obj = {'id':entry.desgn_mast.desgn_mast_id,'name':entry.desgn_mast.desgn_name_short}
            return obj
        return {}
```

```
class Emp_Mast_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    class Meta:
        model = Emp_Mast
        fields = ['emp_mast_id','first_name','last_name','desgn_mast']
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your models relationships, you can achieve your desired response by modifying the serializer class as below:

```
class Emp_Mast_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    desgn_mast = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Emp_Mast
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_desgn_mast(self, obj):
        desgn_trans = Desgn_Trans.objects.get(emp_mast_id=obj.emp_mast_id)
        return desgn_trans.desgn_mast
```

Documentaion: [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/)

You can remove the defined models primary keys, DRF will automatically add them named by default "id"

Comment: Can I use a reverse lookup? The issue I am facing with that is that reverse lookup might return multiple rows, and I just want to select the latest one depending on the latest date. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The reason I want to use reverse lookup is that it will be significantly faster than this. I will have several thousand records and several such fields also. I just showed this for example. So this could become very slow

Comment: Try to modify the query inside the get_desgn_mast(self, obj):
Desgn_Trans.objects.get(emp_mast_id=obj.emp_mast_id).last()

Comment: I think you should try to re-design your models relationships

Comment: Can you give a suggestion?

Comment: I'll try to understand your design, but first what do you mean by mast and trans

Comment: 'mast' means Master and 'trans' means Transaction. Thanks so much for devoting so much time and effort